# Problema en el envío de parámetros en PHP en una llamada SOAP

Tags: php, soap

Tengo problemas al enviar los parámetros en una llamada usando SOAP y PHP.
La llamada debería quedar así:

```xml
<env:Body>
        <ns2:UpdateGuestCardRequest>
            <ns2:NameMembership operaid="1111" primarykey="true" displaySequence="1">
                <ns1:membershipType>PFS</ns1:membershipType>
                <ns1:membershipNumber>29335097</ns1:membershipNumber>
                <ns1:membershipLevel>SILK</ns1:membershipLevel>
            </ns2:NameMembership>
        </ns2:UpdateGuestCardRequest>
    </env:Body>
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```php
 $datos = array("membershipLevel" => "SILK",
                   "membershipType" => "PFS",                 
                   "membershipNumber" => "29335097");

$parameters = array("NameMembership" => array('_' => $datos, "operaId" => $opera_id, 'primary' => "true", "displaySequence" => 1 ));


$respuesta = $cliente_soap->__soapCall('UpdateGuestCard',  array('parameters' => $parameters));
```

Sin embargo cuando imprimo la última llamada realizada `(htmlspecialchars($cliente_soap->__getLastRequest())` veo que la llamada que realiza es la siguiente:

```xml
<env:Body>
  <ns1:UpdateGuestCardRequest>
    <ns1:NameMembership operaId="912351" primary="true" displaySequence="1"/>       </ns1:UpdateGuestCardRequest>
</env:Body>
```

Es decir, que no envía el contenido del array `datos`.
Sé que estoy haciendo algo mal, pero por más que busco no encuentro el problema. ¿Alguna idea?

Añado el código de como estoy generando el soapClient:

```html
        $cliente = new \SoapClient($url, array('encoding' => 'UTF-8',
           "connection_timeout" => 120,
           "trace" => true,
           'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
           'type_name' => 'TPA_ExtensionsType',
           'to_xml' => 'to_soap_anySimpleType_xml',
           'from_xml' => 'from_soap_anySimpleType_xml', 
           'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,         
        ));
```

Añado la documentación que tengo del servicio SOAP de opera.

[image: Documentacion opera soap]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Header>
<OGHeader transactionID="000005" timeStamp="2003-12-08T09:15:27.9431250-05:00"
xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Core/">
<Origin entityID="OWS" systemType="WEB"/>
<Destination entityID="TI" systemType="ORS"/>
</OGHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<UpdateGuestCardRequest xmlns:nm="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Name/"
xmlns:c="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Common/"
xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Name.wsdl">
<NameMembership operaId="1160502" primary="true" displaySequence="1">
<c:membershipType>DL</c:membershipType><c:membershipNumber>DL1234</c:membershipNumber>
<c:memberName>TAMMY KONOPIK</c:memberName>
<c:expirationDate>2015-12-31</c:expirationDate>
<c:inactive>true</c:inactive>
</NameMembership>
</UpdateGuestCardRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Ya lo he añadido.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la parte más relevante del `wsdl` (definición de tipos y de la petición) para poder facilitarnos la reproducción del problema?

Comment: Gracias, he añadido la documentación que tengo del servicio de soap de opera. Espero que sea eso lo que necesitas.